# Multiple usages of same controller in angular

Tags: angularjs

problem with angular. On my website a have comments. Each comment shares the same 'ng-controller="commentCtrl"' directive. Now when I have about 300 comments on my web site, there are 300 commentCtrl instances. In the html of the controller I am using ng-disabled="author_provided()" on a button.
When I am changing the author input text field, all the 300 comments are invoking author_provided() ( because this function depends on on the author ng-model). This causes performance issues. I want the author_provided() function be invoked only in the controller where I am changing the author. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

The author_provided function will be evaluated for each comment on every $digest cycle. If you must circumvent this behavior, I suggest adding the author provided boolean as a property of the comment object. Then your template code can simply read: `ng-disabled=comment.author_provided` (no function call) and Angular will evaluate the result without calling the controller function.

The function is called for every comment because the templating engine can't know the result of ng-disabled for each comment without evaluating the controller function call.